# VBA Macro for updating cells containing INDEX functions that reference an external worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am new to VBA macros so any help is appreciated. I am trying to create a VBA macro that can update multiple cells that contain an INDEX function that directly references an external worksheet. I am not currently using a data connection with this.

My current progress is like this:

```
Sub UpdateIndexFormulasWithFilePathInB2()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim formula As String

    filePath = Range("B2").Value

    For i = 4 To 14
        ' Get the current formula from the cell
        formula = Cells(i, 2).formula

        ' Update the formula to use the file path from cell B2
        formula = Replace(formula, "[OldFilePath]", filePath)

        ' Set the updated formula back in the cell
        Cells(i, 2).formula = formula
    Next i
End Sub
```

I have successfully looped through the cells but I found that I will need to locate and select the reference worksheet for each cell which contains the INDEX function. Is there a way for me to either bypass this completely by having the macro select the file itself or limit the selection to only once to update all the cells with the function since all the cells are referring to the same reference?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can also accomplish this using Find and Replace found on the Ribbon. Take note of the syntax shown in the cell for the external link (it'll be something like `C:\Users\User\Desktop\[TEST.xlsx]`). Then use the same format for the new file path, including the square brackets, and replace all. This can also be done in VBA with the `Range.Replace` method. If you have reason to only target links within `INDEX()` formulas, though, perhaps this won't work as a blanket fix.

Answer (score 0):

- Loop through all sheets and locate the cells with formulas by `SpecialCells`

```vb
Sub UpdateIndexFormulasWithFilePathInB2()
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim sFormula As String
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, formRng As Range
    Const oldFILEPATH = "[OldFilePath]"
    ' Modify sheet name as needed to get the new file path
    filePath = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
    ' Loop through sheets
    For Each oSht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ' Get all cells with formula
        Set formRng = oSht.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23)
        If Not formRng Is Nothing Then
            For Each c In formRng.Cells
                sFormula = c.Formula2
                If VBA.InStr(1, sFormula, "Index", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    c.Formula2 = Replace(sFormula, oldFILEPATH, filePath)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

---

If your expected result is to replace FilePath for all formulas, regardless of whether they contain `Index` in them, the code will be simpler.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Const oldFILEPATH = "[OldFilePath]"
    ' Modify sheet name as needed to get the new file path
    filePath = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
    ' Loop through sheets
    For Each oSht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        oSht.Cells.Replace What:=oldFILEPATH, Replacement:=filePath, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False _
            , FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Next
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.Replace method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, but I ended up settling with using a combination of both VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP and my macro.

The problem with my last code was that in order to update the cells with the INDEX formula that were directly referencing an external file, Excel would create a popup prompt in order to select the reference file for each cell with said formula. I was hoping that the macro would have been able to bypass the prompt completely or at least reduce to only doing it once.

My workaround was basically to fill cells with a formula with locked references that have a macro copy the formula over to a suitable column in order to refresh the values from the external worksheet, this reduced my external file reference pop up to only happen once for all.

Comment: A better method would be to use the [ChangeLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.changelink) method of the Workbook object.  This allows you to change all formual that reference a specific file in one action.